# Lucene.net IndexWriter lock obtains

Tags: c#, lucene.net

been pulling hair out for several hours trying to find a way around a limitation to Lucene.Net (2.9.2)'s FSLock problem.

Basically, identified that whenever a write action against the index is performed a lock gets put on the directory, nothing new. This lock should be released after every addition, but IndexWriter.Unlock just does nothing, so finally figured out that I can release the lock via:

```
FSDirectory.GetLockFactory().ClearLock("write.lock");
```

however, as soon as I try and ensure that my IndexWriter instance has been initialized, do I get a NativeFSLock exception, assuming that the IndexWriter still believes that a lock is persistent on the directory.

Any ideas as to how I can overcome this?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

My IndexWriter instance was not thread-safe.